# Excel 2010: Can I use an OFFSET function to determin RANK range?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to auto-populate a rank for the previous 12 data entries.  (There will be new columns added each month between the rank function and the data)   I tried using offset for the rank range, but it didn't seem to like that very much.    It should work though, right?

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you have a read of [MCVE] please.  At the moment it's hard to guess at an answer so the answer would be "maybe... depends".  Could you post what your data looks like, what you're trying to do, what you expect it to look like afterwards and how far you've got in solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Do you have any mock example or any kind of example of what you have. I would also suggest to show us an example of what you want to achieve.